# Display success/failure message on HTML page

Tags: php, html, forms

From the `HTML` page I am submitting some records to a `PHP` page, where the records will be saved to the DB and then show a

> message saved successfully

message to the user on the same `HTML` page.

When i submit my form, the records are sent to the HTML page and it displays the success message on another page and not on the same HTML page (where the form code is written). How can i correct it?

HTML

```
<form action="save.php" class="tsc_form_contact_dark nolabel" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-input" placeholder="Name (required)" required />
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Email (required)" required />
    <input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
// Do other stuff
echo "Success";
?>
```

Comment: just use a simple redirect back to that form page along with a session message (after you are done with the insertion), after redirection, just have that session message handler on the form page then just echo it then unset it. (kinda like flash session)

Comment: can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set a message variable. Something like this:

```
$msg=isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : "";
<div><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<form action="save.php" class="tsc_form_contact_dark nolabel" method="POST">
//rest of the form
```

And in the php, you need to redirect to the form page something likt this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
// Do other stuff
$msg = "Success";
$redirecturl = "form_page.php?msg=".$msg;
header("Location: $redirecturl");
?>
```

There could be other methods to send result message using session, but I would recommend not doing that.

Comment: the error message does not get displayed.